# Prestapyt and Prestashop 1.6.0.9, error on post

Tags: python, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to follow the example given with prestapyt, I have to sync products and categories from csv files to Prestashop, version 1.6.0.9.

prestapyt says it may not be compatible with version newer than 1.5.9.0.

As in the example my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebService
from xml.etree import ElementTree


prestashop = PrestaShopWebService('http://myshop.com/api','mykey')
prestashop.debug = True

prestashop.get('')

print "ADD"
address = """
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<category>
<id></id>
<id_parent></id_parent>
<active>1</active>
<id_shop_default></id_shop_default>
<is_root_category></is_root_category>
<position></position>
<date_add></date_add>
<date_upd></date_upd>
<name><language id="1">Jackets Exp test</language><language id="2">Giacche exp prova</language></name>
<link_rewrite><language id="1"></language><language id="2"></language></link_rewrite>
<description><language id="1"></language><language id="2"></language></description>
<meta_title><language id="1"></language><language id="2"></language></meta_title>
<meta_description><language id="1"></language><language id="2"></language></meta_description>
<meta_keywords><language id="1"></language><language id="2"></language></meta_keywords>
<associations>
<categories>
<categories>
<id></id>
</categories>
</categories>
<products>
<products>
<id></id>
</products>
</products>
</associations>
</category>
</prestashop>
"""

prestashop.add('categories', address)
```

and this is the answer on server side

```
[error] [client **] [PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1:   parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found   (**/prestashop/trunk/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 1454)
[error] [client **] [PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): %0A%3Cprestashop+xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%3E (**/prestashop/trunk/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 1454)
[error] [client **] [PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ (**/prestashop/trunk/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 1454)
```

So it sounds like it's a encoding error, I tried to edit prestapyt https://github.com/guewen/prestapyt/blob/master/prestapyt/prestapyt.py @ line 283 removing the urlencode, but it didn't work. Help!!! :D